# What does "lassar" mean in "The Most Dangerous Game"?

Tags: meaning, nouns

In the short story "[The Most Dangerous Game](https://archive.org/details/TheMostDangerousGame_129)" (1924) by Richard Connell, Zaroff says

> I hunt the scum of the earth: sailors from tramp ships—**lassars**, blacks, Chinese, whites, mongrels—a thoroughbred horse or hound is worth more than a score of them.

What does *lassars* mean?

Comment: This is probably a misspelling or corruption of [lascar](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lascar), a kind of sailor.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've seen a word quite similar to "lassar" used to refer to a leper.

Comment: Ah, yes -- words like "lazar" and "lazaretto", derived from the name of the biblical figure Lazarus, are sometimes used to refer to leper colonies.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is either a transcription error or a deliberate corruption that was changed in other editions. In various versions of the text you can find on the web, for example, in a lesson in the *[Holt Elements of Literature](http://www.buckeyevalley.k12.oh.us/userfiles/212/Classes/2153/MostDangerousGameHoltReader-0.pdf)*, the quote is rendered

> I hunt the scum of the earth—sailors from tramp ships—**lascars**, blacks, Chinese, 
>   whites, mongrels—a thoroughbred horse or hound is worth more than a score of them.

That same source identifies *lascar* as an East Indian sailor employed on a European ship. The OED defines a *lascar* or *Lascar* more broadly as any East Indian sailor, tracing it to an erroneous European use of the Urdu *lashkar* or *lashkari*, dating in English to about 1625.